# Transfer app from developer to another developer

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, mobile

I want to know what issues gives me Firebase if I transfer an app from one apple developer account to another developer account?

Do I need to modify something on firebase portal?

The bundle ID never will be modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, just make sure to transfer over the GoogleServiceInfo.plist it made you download in the first place if it's a new project, otherwise just leave it as is.

all you'd be doing is changing the developer account its working from

Comment: also, you're not really "transferring" a project over, just working on it from another account.

Comment: ok! thanks! I'll be try it out! just for curiosity, how do you know that information? please don't misunderstood me but if you have a link or something I really appreciate that :)

Comment: There's no link, I'm an iOS developer it's from experience, you shouldn't even need to change the GoogleService file just sign it from the new account after you've got the certificates on the new account

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark correct answer if I helped you :)